# Change max number of characters allowed in a column

Tags: mysql

I am writing a database script to change the maximum number of characters allowed on an existing column.
I want this column to be able to hold more characters, **without deleting it**. 
How would I write the MySQL query for doing something like this?

Comment: what is that field datatype?

Comment: this is a fairly good question, but when you write a question on Stack Overflow there are some things you are supposed to do to make it a better question that wont get you downvotes. Please read [**My Post**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/2733506) on writing SQL questions.. there are many tips and tricks in there for formulating a good question. if you notice in my answer I posted a demo.. things like that are VERY helpful and will get you a better answer faster :)

Comment: Thanks @JohnRuddell am about to read this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can just use MODIFY to increase it

```
ALTER TABLE mytable MODIFY mycolumn VARCHAR(999)
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bb278/1)

you can also use CHANGE instead of MODIFY, but CHANGE will also rename the column so you would either have to provide a new column name or just repeat it a second time

```
ALTER TABLE mytable CHANGE mycolumn mynewcolumn VARCHAR(999)
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a738a/1)

if you note in the second fiddle you will see that the column name is changed and each time i alter the table im inserting characters greater than the allotted number originally set.